# MySQL Workbench Version 8.0.17 dies silently on MacOS Mohave 10.14.6

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

MacOS Version: 10.14.6 Mohave
MySQL Workbench: 8.0.17

Fresh installed (tried uninstall -> install) but not able to understand why it keeps on dying silently. The log file has following contents:

```
14:26:57 [INF][      Workbench]: Starting up Workbench
14:26:57 [INF][   WBContext UI]: Initializing workbench context UI with these values:
    base dir: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources
    plugin path: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns
    struct path: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/grt
    module path: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns:/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins
    library path: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries
    user data dir: /Users/mg/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench
    open at start: 
    open type: 
    run at startup: 
    run type: 
    Force SW rendering: No
    Force OpenGL: No
    quit when done: No
14:26:57 [INF][      WBContext]: WbContext::init
```

The logs goes silent post this. No idea, what am I missing.

Comment: This is the entire log you get? Check previous log files (Help -> Locate Log Files) to see if there's something usable. Additionally open the console.app and watch the error list when you launch Workbench. Does it show anything related to it there?

Comment: thanks. That's all the log I get. I checked all previous log files as well and they all have exactly same logs. I did not try the console.app, will do.

Comment: Oct 10 06:55:45 > com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench.34132[11619]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1 . (This is all I could get from Console).

Comment: Try removing/renaming the user data dir before starting Workbench again.